# Writing a structure containing a string into a binary file

Tags: c, linux, binaryfiles

I have a binary file where I log the offset at which writes to other files occur and the data that is written at that offset. Now I define the structure of each log record as

```
struct log_record{
                    int offset;
                    char *data;
               }
struct log_record t;
```

When I write the record into the file, I have the length of data that I write into the file and hence before assigning I allocate space as

```
t.data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(buff));/*buf holds the data to be written*/
```

Now I have the length of the record I am writing into the file...But the issue is while reading. How do I allocate space against a structure that I read the record into and in the fread what should be the size of the record. Am a few confused.
 Would be gratefull for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write the length of the string as the length of string is variable.

Note that `strlen()` doesn't return the size including the terminating NULL.

**EDIT** + **EDIT 2** (thanks to mu is too short) + **EDIT 3** (thanks to mu is too short)

This is how I'd do it:

```
t.data = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(buff) + 1);
strcpy(t.data, buff);

// ...
int data_size = strlen(t.data) + 1;
fwrite(&t.offset,  1, sizeof(t.offset),   file);
fwrite(&data_size, 1, sizeof(data_size),  file);
fwrite(t.data,     1, strlen(t.data) + 1, file);
```

Comment: @Donotalo..Am sorry but did not get you

Comment: @mu is too short: what i was proposing is not the edit! thanks for pointing my mistake. i'm going to edit.

Comment: @mu is too short: checked. :)

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid writing whole structures to disk and reading them back in again. You'll run into problems with different architectures and, as you've noticed, pointers and variable length data structures. Instead, marshal the data by hand on output and put it back together when you read it.

In your specific case, instead of writing a `struct log_record`, you want to write three things:

- The `offset` (choose your size and byte order and stick to it).
- The length of `data` (in the same format as above).
- The actual bytes of `data`.

Then, when you're reading the data back in, read in the `offset` and rearrange its bytes to match the local byte order. Then read the length (in the same way as `offset`). Now you know how big the `data` is so you can allocate your memory and slurp it off the disk with a single call to `fread`.

Oh and don't cast the return value of `malloc`, there's no need for it and it can hide problems. Instead, just say this:

```
/* See above for how to figure out data_length. */
t.data = malloc(sizeof(char) * data_length);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write structs with variable sizes to a binary file, and then read them back again without any record of their size. You could either use a char array with a fixed size instead of a char pointer, or use a custom file format where you record the size of each element if you need them to be of variable length.

Since I didn't have anything better to do, I wrote a  little program which I hope does what you are looking for. No error checking :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct {
    int offset;
    int length;
    char *data;
} log_record;

void write_to_file(const char *filename)
{
    log_record lr;
    const int num_records = 10;
    char buf[100];
    int i;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(filename, "wb");

    for(i = 0; i < num_records; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(buf, "Data entry %d goes here. Beware of size limit!", i);
        lr.length = strlen(buf) + 1;
        lr.offset = i;
        lr.data = malloc(sizeof(char) * lr.length);
        strncpy(lr.data, buf, lr.length);   
        fwrite(&lr.offset, sizeof(lr.offset), 1, fp);
        fwrite(&lr.length, sizeof(lr.length), 1, fp);
        fwrite(lr.data, sizeof(char), lr.length, fp);   
        free(lr.data);
    }   
    fclose(fp); 
}

void read_from_file(const char * filename)
{
    log_record lr;
    int tmp;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");

    while (feof(fp) == 0) 
    {
        tmp = fgetc(fp);
        if(tmp != EOF)
        {
            ungetc(tmp, fp);            
            fread(&lr.offset, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
            fread(&lr.length, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
            lr.data = malloc(sizeof(char) * lr.length);
            fread(lr.data, sizeof(char), lr.length, fp);
            free(lr.data);      
        }
    }
    fclose(fp); 
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    write_to_file("temp.bin");  
    read_from_file("temp.bin"); 
    return 0;
}
```